# Hollow Diamond in Python with recursion

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a diamond out of forward and backwards slashes, so far I have this piece of code:

```
def upper_diamond(level,length):
if level <=length:
    print(" " * (length - level), end="")
    print("/", end="")
    print(" " * 2 * (level-1), end=" ")
    print("\\")
    upper_diamond(level + 1,length)

def lower_diamond(level,length):


def diamond(length):
    upper_diamond(1,length)

diamond(4)
```

and when I print it comes out as such:

```
   / \
  /   \
 /     \
/       \
```

I want to make a complete diamond and making the bottom part is stumping me, how do I make the bottom half print with the rest of the diamond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing off your code, you can replicate the same behavior adjusting the offsets (changed `end` after spacing section to empty string to avoid opened edges):

```
def upper_diamond (level, length):
    if level <= length:
        print(' ' * (length - level), end='')
        print('/', end='')
        print(' ' * 2 * (level - 1), end='')
        print('\\')
        upper_diamond(level + 1, length)

def lower_diamond (level, length):
    if level <= length:
        print(' ' * (level - 1), end='')
        print('\\', end='')
        print(' ' * 2 * (length - level), end='')
        print('/')
        lower_diamond(level + 1, length)

def diamond(length):
    upper_diamond(1, length)
    lower_diamond(1, length)

diamond(4)
```

Outputs:

```
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
/      \
\      /
 \    /
  \  /
   \/
```

Comment: Is there an alternative method to adding to the code I already have?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! getting that last part confused me to no end, this helps for sure.

Comment: @L.Jones however, this one is not a good exercise for recursive functions, because it could be done more cleanly and efficiently using for and ranges (`for level in range(1, length+1)`), see my editing history for more details. Recursively speaking, you did a pretty good work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify it into a single function where you can specify the size and the characters used for each side of the diamond. Rather than printing each line, it might be cleaner to build the entire string with the function then print the returned string.

```
def build_diamond(half_width=4, char_tl='/', char_tr='\\', char_bl='\\', char_br='/'):
    top_rows = []
    bot_rows = []
    for i in range(half_width):
        offset = (half_width - i - 1)
        top_rows.append(offset * ' ' + (2 * i * ' ').join((char_tl, char_tr)))
        bot_rows.append(i * ' ' + (2 * offset * ' ').join((char_bl, char_br)))
    return '\n'.join(top_rows + bot_rows)

print(build_diamond())
```

Result:

```
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
/      \
\      /
 \    /
  \  /
   \/
```